# Split a file into variable quantities and directories based on csv using linux

Tags: linux, bash, csv, split

I have a spreadsheet with a list of directories, and an associated variable number of 'accounts' needed to be assigned to each directory (could easily be converted to csv) ie:

```
directory                  # of accounts needed
/usr/src/Mon-Carlton/      110
/usr/src/Mon-CoalMtn/      50                                                                                    
/usr/src/Mon-Cumming/      90
etc...
```

I also have a 'master_account_list.csv' file that contains the full list of all possible accounts available to be distributed to each area ie:

```
account_1,password,type
account_2,password,type
account_3,password,type
etc...
```

I would like to be able to script the splitting of the master_account_list.csv into a separate accounts.csv file for each unique directory with the listed # of accounts needed.

The master_file gets updated with fresh accounts often and there is a need to redistribute again to all the directories.  (The resulting accounts.csv file has the same formatting as the master_account_list.)

What is the best way to accomplish then in Linux?

Edit:  When the script is complete, it would be ideal if the remainder of unassigned accounts from the master_account_list.csv became the new master_account_list.csv.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45724561/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've converted the accounts spreasheet to a comma(!) separated csv file, without headers(!), you can use the following `awk` program:

*split_accounts.awk*:

```
# True as long as we are reading the first file which
# is the converted spreadsheet
NR==FNR {
    # Store the directories and counts in arrays
    dir[NR]=$1
    cnt[NR]=$2
    next
}

# This block runs for every line of master_account_list.csv
{
    # Get the directory and count from the arrays we've
    # created above. 'i' will get initialized automatically
    # with 0 on it's first usage
    d=dir[i+1]
    c=cnt[i+1]

    # append the current line to the output file
    f=d"account_list.csv"
    print >> f

    # 'n' holds the number of accounts placed into the current
    # directory. Check if it has the reached the desired count
    if(++n==c) {
        # Step to the next folder / count
        i++
        # Reset the number of accounts placed
        n=0
        # Close the previous output file
        close(f)
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -F, -f split_accounts.awk accounts.csv master_account_list.csv
```

Note: `0` is not allowed for the count in the current implementation.

Comment: Thank you -- this works great! ... ..and I apologize for being new to Linux and the awk commands.   Appreciate these starter tips very much :-)

Comment: ...follow up:  I noticed this appends the existing file and I want to replace.  I also need a single line header in the new file.   Currently I am replacing each file with a batch `cp` to copy a new blank file that also includes a header to each directory.  Then I run this script.  Can I use awk to accomplish the same?